How to use relationship in sqlalchemy database Table?
I need to get a list of a model's properties which are actually relationships (that is, they were created by relationship()).

User= Table(
"users", metadata, Column("id",Integer,primary_key=True,index=True),
Column("name",String,nullable=False) )
Book = Table(
"books", metadata, Column("id",Integer,primary_key=True,index=True),
Column("title",String,nullable=False),
Column("user_id",Integer,ForeignKey("users.id")) )

how to use: user_obj.books(relationship)
